# Python script with schedule through windows terminal

Tags: windows, python-3.x, terminal, schedule

I have a python scipt that use the module schedule to schedule a job. I launch the script from a Windows terminal.
Sometimes, it works well, but some other times, the script seems to freeze during the job and a I have to press 'enter' in the terminal to continue the job...

My script is like :

```
def Job():
   print(datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S UTC")))

   utcnow = datetime.utcnow()
   some_script_that_save_utcnow_in_a_csv
```

My schedule is configured to run every 15 minutes. 
Now the strange behavior :

- it's 13h21 : the job should have been launched at 13h15 but nothing is printed.
- I press enter.
- 11/10/17 13:15:00 UTC is printed in the terminal.
- In the csv, the time saved is 11/10/17 13:21:00 UTC.

So it seems the code was blocked just after the print...

Any idea of what is happening? I'm thinking maybe the terminal is waiting the user to press 'enter' before flushing sys.stdout ...

Comment: It was likely blocked printing to stdout. Do you have this running attached to a standard Windows console with a visible window? If so, by any chance do you have the console's quick-edit mode enabled? Writing to the console will block if the user is copying text, which can accidentally happen with a stray click in quick-edit mode.

Comment: Yes I'm in quick-edit mode... I'm deactivating the mode to see if it changes the behavior

Comment: Okay it seems to work great !  thank you

Comment: FYI, with quick-edit mode disabled, you can use mark mode to select text with the mouse. Ctrl+M activates mark mode. Pressing enter copies the selected text and exits mark mode.